# Applying Seperate Resource Filters for each configuration in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, build

I have two folders (folderA, folderB) in Eclipse with a different main() method in each one. I want to create two different configurations to compile/build each program separately without compiling the other program.

I am aware that Eclipse has resource filter in

```
Project -> Resource -> Resource Filters
```

But how can I specify a different resource filters for each configuration?